# Unable to cover specific lines in Angular method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage

I have this class where I am using a couple of services to get data and then transform it and return it as observable. Test coverage is not covering just one specific part of it no matter what I try. Tried various different things but it is not covering. This is the class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AccountDetail } from '../../models/accounts';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { AccountDescriptionHelper } from '../../utils/account-subaccount';
import { GroupService } from '../group-structure';
import { TreeNode } from '../../models/treeNode';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountsChartService {
  private readonly ENDPOINT = `${environment}/ac`;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private groupService: GroupService,
    private accountDescriptionHelper: AccountDescriptionHelper
  ) {}

  loadAccountByChartService(bT: string, cT: string): Observable<Node[]> {
    const accountSubaccountDescEP = `${this.ENDPOINT}/cT/${cT}/ad`;
    let aCBS = new Subject<Node[]>();
    let aSAD = new Subject<AccountDetail[]>();
    this.http
      .get<AccountDetail[]>(accountSubaccountDescEP)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.accountDescriptionHelper.storeMapFromDescriptionList(response);
        aSAD.next(response);
      });

      aSAD.subscribe(list => {
      this.groupService.getGroupedAccounts(cT, bT, list).subscribe(response => {
        aCBS.next(response);
      });
    });
    return aCBS.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Here are the test:

```
it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

it('test', () => {
    httpClient = createHttpClient();

    service = new AccountsChartService(httpClient as HttpClient, groupService, asdHelper);
    const a = spyOn(groupService, 'getGroupedAccounts')
    const result = service.testMethod('1', 'Test');

    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    result.subscribe(() => {
      expect(a).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

It is saying this specific part is uncovered but I don't know how I can assert and manipulate **aCBS** and **aSAD**. I have tried moving them as class instance variables but same thing. Just not sure what to do. Thanks for looking. Hope to get resolution.

It is saying this part is uncovered, everything else is showing as covered:

```
list => {
      this.groupService.getGroupedAccounts(cT, bT, list).subscribe(response => {
        aCBS.next(response);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of (potential) issues there. First of all, rewrite your method.

```
loadAccountByChartService(bT: string, cT: string): Observable<Node[]> {
  const accountSubaccountDescEP = `${this.ENDPOINT}/cT/${cT}/ad`;

  return this.http.get<AccountDetail[]>(accountSubaccountDescEP).pipe(
    tap(response => this.accountDescriptionHelper.storeMapFromDescriptionList(response)),
    switchMap(response => this.groupService.getGroupedAccounts(cT, bT, response)),
  );
}
```

Now your testcase. Async code is async code, no matter if in a service, a component or unit test. The expect in the suscription block is called after the unit test method ends. There are several ways to handle async unit test. The easiest change in your case would be to simply add the `done` callback.

```
it('test', done => {
    httpClient = createHttpClient();

    service = new AccountsChartService(httpClient as HttpClient, groupService, asdHelper);
    const a = spyOn(groupService, 'getGroupedAccounts')
    const result = service.testMethod('1', 'Test');

    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    result.subscribe(() => {
      expect(a).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I recommand, however, to get into touch with marble testing when testing async code.